# MYSQL insert give 404 error

Tags: php, mysql, http-status-code-404

When I use this script it get: The requested URL /StockManager/Product_Submit.php was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

and it doesn't enter anything in to the MYsql Database.

This is my script:

```
<?php
include 'Connect.php';
$ProName=htmlspecialchars($_POST["ProName"]);
$ProBuyprice=htmlspecialchars($_POST["ProBuyprice"]);
$ProWooPrice=htmlspecialchars($_POST["ProductWooPrice"]);
$WooId=htmlspecialchars($_POST["WooId"]);
$ProEbayPrice=htmlspecialchars($_POST["ProductEbayPrice"]);
$EbayId=htmlspecialchars($_POST["EbayId"]);
$ProQun=htmlspecialchars($_POST["ProQun"]);
$id=htmlspecialchars($_POST["userid"]);

$sql = ("INSERT INTO SoftwProducts(userid, Name, Qun, WooId, EbayId, BuyPrice, WooSelling, ebaySelling)
VALUES ($id,$ProName,$ProQun, $WooId, $EbayId, $ProBuyprice, $ProWooPrice, $ProEbayPrice)");

if (!mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
{
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}
echo "Success!";
?>
```

When I remove the if statement and just do:

```
mysqli_query($conn,$sql)
```

I don't receive the 404 error.
What am I doing wrong.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: 404 is HTTP page not found error, you are posting data to a page which does not exists.

Comment: MySQL doesn't give a 404 error, your web server does. The path to your PHP script is wrong.

Comment: I don't see any way that adding or removing the `if` statement could affect this error. The only way editing the script could cause or fix a 404 is if the script performs a redirect, and it redirects to a nonexistent URL.

Comment: Try to manually connect to your MySQL server. Check if you receive the same error.

Comment: The database is fine as I am able to grab data from it, its only when i want to send data to it through php. I have checked the URL, coped and pasted it from the original file title(sits on the same server) still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

404 Error is Not Found Error, provided by HTTP. That means that the page (which is mentioned in your post as `/StockManager/Product_Submit.php` does not exist.

As it appears to me, you probably used wrong `action` attribute in the `form` (check lower/upper cases) or you are using wrong redirect somewhere in the script.

Comment: The form action is: form action="Product_Submit.php" method="post"

Comment: @millsons And in which folder is the form located? Could you provide me with more of your directory structure?

Comment: @ FanaticD All the files are in the same folder temperately.

Comment: @millsons And is that folder /StockManager/? Where "/" infront of the rest of the name implies that it is in the root of the file system? It would be better if you could edit the original post and add the form and the rest of the files you consider useful for us.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = ("INSERT INTO SoftwProducts(userid, Name, Qun, WooId, EbayId,    BuyPrice, WooSelling, ebaySelling)
VALUES ($id,$ProName,$ProQun, $WooId, $EbayId, $ProBuyprice, $ProWooPrice, $ProEbayPrice)");

if (!mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
{
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}
echo "Success!";
```

to:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO SoftwProducts(userid, Name, Qun, WooId, EbayId, BuyPrice, WooSelling, ebaySelling)
VALUES ($id,'$ProName',$ProQun, $WooId, $EbayId, $EbayId, $ProWooPrice, $ProEbayPrice)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

Thank you for the help anyway :-)